# Classifier performance on subset of data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I'm using Weka to perform classification on a set of labelled web pages, and measuring classifier performance with AUC. I have a separate six-level factor that is not used in classification, and I'd like to know how well classifiers perform on each level of the factor.

What techniques or measures should I use to test classifier performance on a subset of data?

Comment: you ask "What techniques or measures should I use to test classifier performance on a subset of data?", but say that MCC and Cohen's kappa don't answer your question. Would you mind clarifying it?

Comment: My question is about assessing classifier performance on a _specific subset_, not a general question about measuring classifier performance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are asking, but people often use [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) to break a single set of data into multiple training/testing subsets to better evaluate learning performance.

The basic idea (for e.g. 10-fold cross-validation) is to:

1. randomly split your data into training and testing sets
2. train a classifier on the training set
3. evaluate its performance on the testing set
4. repeat steps 1-3 nine more times with different random training/testing splits

The overall performance of the classifier is its average performance on all 10 testing sets.

I looked around a bit and found [some examples of how to perform cross-validation programmatically](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+cross-validation+folds+(Java+approach)) or [via the Weka UI](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2892691/WEKA-ExperimenterTutorial).

Comment: Thanks, I'm already performing cross-validation on the entire data set. After the cross-validation, I want to know how well the classifier performed on each of my factor subsets.

Comment: Alas.  You might get a few more answers if you added a bit more explanation describing your 6-level factor, why evaluating it is a problem, what you've already tried, etc.

Comment: Users make a relevance judgment about a page, which is my class variable. They also rate the page's "depth" on a six-point scale. I build a classifier based on extracted features (text, link text, number of headings, number of links, for example). I want to know how well the classifier performs at each level of depth.

Comment: And the problem is that, while I have no problem evaluating the classifier's performance overall, I have no idea how to evaluate performance on a particular subset. So I haven't tried anything yet :)

Comment: @michaeltwofish: There must be something I'm missing, what's wrong with just calculating AUC separately on the particular subsets of interest?

Comment: @qdjm It's much more likely I'm missing something :) I didn't even think of calculating AUC separately from the overall results. I'll investigate that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The steps that Nate Kohl [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663605/classifier-performance-on-subset-of-data/3668447#3668447) are all correct. Another, very important question is the function for measuring the performance. In my experience, maximizing the AUC can sometimes lead to substantial bias of the classifier. I prefer using [Matthews Correlation Coeficient (MCC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient) for binary classifiers or [Cohen's kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) for categorical classifiers with more than two possible values

Comment: Yes, the steps are correct for cross-validation, but as I said, that's not actually what I was asking.